# ATMega 48P powering two DC motors with FPWM Timers, in assembly not C

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

So I'm trying to do my lab assignment and keep running into this issue with setting up my pins to pulse. I want to use two timers in PWM mode to generate a sinusoid to drive my motors. I need to have the timers flicker a port at one time '(OCR*A)' and then flicker again at another '(OCR*B)' and reset the counter back to zero.

I don't care too much which pin on a port it flickers as long as I can control the difference between OCR*A and OCR*B so i can get 70% power in one and 30% in another for example. I want two timers so I have independent motor control but if I can do it with one timer that is okay as well, as long as the motors can be set to different duty cycles.

There is one last catch, all of my code has to be in assembly code. I don't want you to write my code for me, but I have been through my manual over and over and am stumped on how I have set the timer wrong.

Here's the code I have so far. The way my code is written I think it should flicker OCR2A and OCR0A but I am not sure. Please let me know and thank you again.

```
    .INCLUDE <m48Pdef.inc>; Include in program 



    .CSEG; Start code segment. 

    .ORG 0x0000

RJMP MAIN

    MAIN:
LDI R16, LOW(RAMEND)
OUT SPL, R16
LDI R16, HIGH(RAMEND)
OUT SPH, R16

SBI DDRD, 3     ; set correct pins to read and write
SBI DDRD, 2
SBI DDRD, 1
SBI DDRD, 0
SBI DDRB, 3     ; set correct pins to read and write
SBI DDRB, 2
SBI DDRB, 1
SBI DDRB, 0


CLR R16
CLR R17
CLI ;clear global interrupts


LDI R16, 0b01000011 
STS 0xB0, R16
LDI R16, 0b00001011 
STS 0xB1, R16

CLI


LDI R17, 0b01000011 
STS 0x44, R17
LDI R17, 0b00001011 
STS 0x45, R17


LDI R19, 7
LDI R18, 3

SEI

    LOOP:

RCALL DelayA
STS OCR2A, R18
STS OCR0A, R18
STS OCR2B, R19
STS OCR0B, R19
LDI R20, 0xFF
LDI R22, 0x00
LDI R23, 0x00
RCALL DelayA
RJMP LOOP       ;repeats loop to keep the output going

    DelayA:
CP r20, r22 ;standard double nested delay loop
BREQ RELOOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
Dec r20
ldi r21, 0xFF
RJMP DelayB

    DelayB:
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
CP r21, r22
BREQ DelayA
Dec r21
RJMP DelayB

    RELOOP:
RET
```

---

Comment: What is the behavior now (versus the desired behavior)?  Note that you cannot generate a sinusoid wave from a microprocessor: only a square wave (which you might condition to look more like a sinusoid).

Comment: Hi! Yes you are correct about the square waves bit, apologies I should have been more clear. The behavior now is that it seems to not be flickering the ports at all. I plugged in an led module to see if the desired ports were flickering and they were not, I then plugged in the desired ports to the drive signal ports on the motors (which already had power of course) and they made a slight hum and then nothing. I need to make 2 ports flicker in pwm mode so i can drive the motors at varying speeds and as of now the ports do not flicker.

Comment: I am not 100% clear on what you are trying to do..  do you just need two pins (not ports!) to output a PWM signal at a particular frequency/duty cycle, or is it more than that?  The word "flicker" is confusing.

Comment: Yes, i need two different pins on separate ports(B,C, or D) to output a pwm using the 8 bit timer counters. That pwm signal will be used to drive DC motors on a robot at varying speeds depending on the pwm signal.

Comment: Its an ATMega 48P with 3 built in timer counters. Timer counters 2 and 0 are 8bit and timer counter 1 is 16bit. I want to use counters 0 and 2 to produce two separate pwm signals to drive two separate motors. I thought the timers were set up to flicker two specific pins(one each) but they are not flickering. I need to set my timers up to do this so I need help. Hope that explains it. Thank you again really, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in ARV Assembly, but here are the issues I see:

- You are using `STS` to try to load data into timer registers, but what you need to use is the `OUT` instruction. `STS` is "Store direct to SRAM": the timer control registers are.. well... registers, and are loaded via `out` instructions. There is an assembly example for `TIMER1` on page 114 of the datasheet.
- Before you set bits in reneral-purpose registers and load them into timer control registers you probably want to make sure that the registers contain nothing in them to start with.  Use the `LDI` instruction for that, for instance.  There are probably better ways of zero-ing out a register, so google for that (like I said, I don't program much in AVR assembly)
- In general, read the datasheet: I don't see any PWM setting instructions in what you are doing.

The registers you need to worry about for getting PWM to work on AVR are:

- Load `TCCR_A` with bits that set which pins you want to be connected to the timer. For instance, the `COM0A_` bits allows `OC0A` pin to be PWM-ed automatically, whereas `COM0B_` bits allows pin `OC0B` to be PWMed (datasheet pages 104-105).
- Both `TCCR_A` and `TCCR_B` must have the `WGM__` bits set correctly to specify the waveform generation mode. Most likely you want one of the Fast PWM modes.
- `TCCR_B` also specifies the frequency of your PWM via the prescaler `CS__` bits. The frequency will be the CPU clock speed divided by some factor (prescaler value of 1 for the fastest). See datasheet page 108 for TIMER0.
- Finally `OCR_A` and `OCR_B` registers set the duty cycle for the `OC_A` and `OC_B` pins respectively. In non-inverting PWM modes the corresponding pin is set at BOTTOM, and then cleared when `TCNT` (the timer counter) reaches the value in `OC_A`/`OC_B`. So if you are doing Fast PWM on timer 0 and `OC0A` is connected to timer output in non-inverting mode (`COM0A1` bit is set, `COM0A0` bit is cleared in `TCCR0A`), a value of `0x3F` in `OCR01` will give you a 25% duty cycle on pin `OC0A` (if your timer prescaler bits are more than `0`(0=timer stopped) and less than `0x06` (`0x06` and `0x07` in `CS0_` bits specifies external clock source).
- You do not need interrupts or overflow. Assuming you set the registers described above correctly, the ATmega will do the PWMing for you.

Comment: So it tried swapping some of the sts commands to outs and now the commands are out of range, which makes no sense because in essence there is nothing to be out of range of. Also what I have tried to set in my timer counters should have enabled FastPWM on two different pins but hasn't. I made a slight code revision but I thought my original code was ready to set these pins for fastPWM or I wouldn't have posted it. I removed the timer overflow part of the code but that didn't even help. I'm simulating with my port display open and no pins are being flickered at all. Just being set to write.

Comment: good news is I fixed it, bad news is i can't post it until the assignment is turned in and semester over :(